# Proxy for downloading with libvideo in C#

Tags: c#, proxy, youtube, youtube-dl

Is anyone familiar with `libvideo`? I have `[libvideo][1]` in an application.

How can I inject the proxy config into the `libvideo`?

```
using VideoLibrary;

void SaveVideoToDisk(string link)
{
    var youTube = YouTube.Default; // starting point for YouTube actions
    var video = youTube.GetVideo(link); // gets a Video object with info about the video
    File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\" + video.FullName, video.GetBytes());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `libvideo` does not support proxy. So I have to use `youtube-dl` and corrected the above code

```
public static void YouTubeDownloaderWithProxy(string link, string path)
{
    Process youTube = new Process();
    try
    {
        string code = link.Split('/').LastOrDefault();
        string proxy = @"http://....:8585/";
        string youtubeUrl = @"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + "code";

        youTube.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        youTube.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        youTube.StartInfo.FileName = Application.StartupPath + @"\youtube-dl.exe";
        youTube.StartInfo.Arguments = $"--proxy {proxy} -o '{path}' {youtubeUrl}";

        youTube.Start();
        youTube.WaitForExit();
        youTube.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }

}
```